# colspan messes with fixed width table

Tags: css

I want a fixed-width table with 1 small and 2 large columns like so:

```
|..|....|....|
|..|....|....|
|..|....|....|
```

using

```
td.small { width: 20% }
td.large { width: 40% }
```

---

Then I want to add an extra large col with colspan=2 like so

```
|.......|....|
|..|....|....|
|..|....|....|
```

using

```
td.small { width: 20% }
td.large { width: 40% }
td.extralarge { width: 60% } /* 20+40=60 */
```

---

But I keep ending up with:

```
|.......|....|
|...|...|....|
|...|...|....|
```

---

A more graphical example [is found on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eqonow/1/edit)

[image: js-bin screenshot]

** **edit** **

Sorry, I missed one detail:
I must use (or so I think..?) `table-layout: fixed` since I'm having some special overflowing properties of the cells:

```
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Updated jsbin found here](http://jsbin.com/eqonow/2/).

Comment: Simply remove the table layout

Comment: @Naveen yes it worked, but I simplified my example too much. See updated question.

Comment: Try giving `display: table-row` to each element.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could also use `colgroup` and `col` to set the width:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="short" />
        <col span="2" class="long" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With this CSS:

```
table { width: 100%; }
.short {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 20%
}
.long {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 40%;
}
.multiCells { background: #F3A633; }
```

This way you do not need to give every `td` a class, makes it easier when you want to change the classname.

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/3VLwL/)**

**[colgroup MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup)**

Comment: don't know about `colgroup`, but simple `col`s solved the problem

Comment: when you have `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` then `colgroup` must be before them right inside `table`

Answer (score 16):

change the table-layout: fixed to auto

```
table {
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

Find the working demo here: http://jsbin.com/atohug/2/edit

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but I simplified my example too much. See updated question.

Answer (score 10):

LinkinTED provided a workable solution, but the example doesn't directly address the OP's issue or explain why it works.
The example should look like this (borrowing the same syntax)

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="short" />
        <col span="2" class="long" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Extra long content</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
        <td>Long long long long</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The OP's issue was that when you use table-layout: fixed the table expects every cell's width to be clearly defined in the first row so that it doesn't have to resize the columns as more content is added to subsequent cells in later rows.    However, if you use colspan=2  in the first row, it has no idea how wide those two cells are, so it defaults to 50% of their combined width and that decision is fixed for the rest of the table.   By using colgroup and specifying the  widths for each column, the table can fix the column widths up front and you're free to use colspan=2 (or more) on the first row.

One caveat.   col width=  only supports pixels and %.   If you need to use other units of width, associate col with a style as above.

Answer (score 8):

I know that this post is really old but maybe my solution will help someone.
You can do the fake row on the top and hide it by setting each cell's height to 0. This will help the table-layout fixed calculate the desired cell sizes.

```
<table>
<tr class="hidden-row">
    <td>Short</td>
    <td>Long long long long</td>
    <td>Long long long long</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>Extra long content</td>
    <td>Long long long long</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Short</td>
    <td>Long long long long</td>
    <td>Long long long long</td>
</tr>
```

```
tr.hidden-row td {
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, easy to implement solution ! New ideas to old problems are alway worthy. Thanks !