# Why HTML Table column width doesn't work with fixed-layout and 100% width?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

When table use fixed-layout and I set its width to 100% it ignores the column width and makes it all even. Why?

This is how the table look without 100% width.

[image]

But when I set table width as 100% all columns became even

[image]

**How to fix that?** I can't remove 'fixed-layout' or the 'merged th', I need it both, and also need to make table 100% wide.

(actually I can detect that table uses 100% width and replace 'merged th' with `div` before the table, but would be better to find a proper way to fix it)

The code

```html
<style>
  th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
  table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" width="100%">100% united th</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 20%;">20% th</th>
    <th style="width: 80%;">80% th</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#values: _"`fixed`:
Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths."_

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue. I wanted the my tables to extend 100% of screen width, but  then it wouldn't auto resize based on the contents. I ended removing the width: 100% and then it worked. I did also have to add `white-space: nowrap`. Finally, I determined that I should have different styles for different table types. Lesson learned

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `<colgroup>` should be used to fix that, [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831358/colspan-messes-with-fixed-width-table) explaining why it happens.

```html
<style>
  th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
  table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 20%;">
    <col style="width: 80%;">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" width="100%">100% united th</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>20% th</th>
    <th>80% th</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```