# Font Size in Merged Colspan Causes Column Widths in Other Rows to Change

Tags: html, css, html-table

The first, black column in the second row should be much thinner (1%), but the large font in the first row causes it to be too wide.  In fact, the width of that first column in the second row changes along with any changes in the font size of the text in the first row.  Why?  Aren't these rows independent?

```html
<table style="background-color:#420E0E;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;">
  <tr style="height:5%;">
    <td colspan="2">
      <table style="border:1px solid #fff;width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td style="border:1px solid #fff;color:white;font-size:100pt;">Home</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:95%;">
    <td style="background-color:#000000;border:1px solid #fff;width:1%;"></td>
    <td style="background-color:#422E0E;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S., seems similar to this posting: 
[Colspan on cell in one row seems to prevent setting TD width in all the other rows. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835756/colspan-on-cell-in-one-row-seems-to-prevent-setting-td-width-in-all-the-other-ro)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you didn't mentioned the `width` in the second column on the second row.

Apply `width:99%` to the second column.

This is because your table has **[`table-layout:auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)** property...It means the column `width` is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells.

***Stack Snippet***

```html
<table style="background-color:#420E0E;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;">
  <tr style="height:5%;">
    <td colspan="2">
      <table style="border:1px solid #fff;width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td style="border:1px solid #fff;color:white;font-size:100pt;">Home</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:95%;">
    <td style="background-color:#000000;border:1px solid #fff;width:1%;"></td>
    <td style="background-color:#422E0E;border:1px solid #fff;width:99%;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, that doesn't work.  You can try it right here above (in StackOverflow) and see the result.

Comment: @swabygw in the above snippet first column has `width:1%` and second column has `width:99%`....thats what you want right..?

Comment: Correct, but your advice of applying the "width:99%" doesn't work - it doesn't fix the width of the first column.  It's also unnecessary because it will default to 99% anyway as it is the only remaining cell.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @swabygw table does not works like div...here `table-layout` plays a important part to decide the width of the cells...[**Table-Layout CSS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)